# Flatten a nested objects to one dimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested objects in this structure:

```
myArray = {
  "D": {
    "U": {
      "A300": "B300",
      "A326": "B326",
      "A344": "B344",
      "A345": "B345"
    },
    "P": {
      "A664": "B664",
      "A756": "B756"
    }
  },
  "I": {
    "U": {
      "A300": "B300",
      "A326": "B326"
    },
    "P": {
      "A756": "B756"
    }
  }
};
```

I am trying to get the data out of it to be only one dimensional (Flatten). I tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
var myNewArray = [].concat.apply([], myArray);
```

and

```
var myNewArray = myArray.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev.concat(curr);
});
```

I want `myNewArray` to have `["B300","B326","B344","B345","B664","B756"]`

Comment: Second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Already tried that and it gives an error about the reduce function

Comment: I think you are working with an object here, not an array

Comment: @Andy Doesn't work if the elements aren't all in `myArray[0][0][0]`: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ryfwudqd/2/

Comment: edited the question as it is an array of objects but it ends with an string which I want to get

Comment: @SMH, if you had an array of objects, the first key would be numerical...

Comment: I already added the actual array in the question

Comment: @SMH It is not an array, it is an object.

Comment: array of objects

Comment: @SMH Nope. Just a nested object.

Comment: you are right, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = [];
myArray[0][0] = [];
myArray[0][0][0] = [];
myArray[0][0][1] = [];
myArray[0][1] = [];
myArray[0][1][0] = [];

myArray[0][0][0][0] = "abc1";
myArray[0][0][0][1] = "abc2";
myArray[0][0][1][0] = "abc3";
myArray[0][1][0][1] = "abc4";
myArray[0][1][0][1] = "abc5";


function flat(acc, val){
  if(Array.isArray(val)){
     acc = acc.concat(val.reduce(flat, []));
  }else{
   acc.push(val);
  }
  return acc;
}

var newMyArray = myArray.reduce(flat, []);
console.log(newMyArray);
```

What this does is to recursively reduce all the inner values that are arrays.

It seems that you're dealing with an object. The previous title of your question and the name of the variable are misleading.

In any case, flattening an object is a very similar process.

```js
var myArray = {"D":{"U":{"A300":"B300","A326":"B326","A344":"B344","A345":"B345"},"P":{"A664":"B664","A756":"B756"}},"I":{"U":{"A300":"B300","A326":"B326"},"P":{"A756":"B756"}}};

function flatObj(obj){
   return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(acc, key){
     if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
        acc = acc.concat(flatObj(obj[key]));
     }else{
        acc.push(obj[key]);
     }
     return acc;
   }, []);
}


var newMyArray = flatObj(myArray);
console.log(newMyArray);
```

Comment: Looks nice, except he's changed the question to an array of objects, not array of arrays.

Comment: @SMH I've edited my answer to make to add an example for flattening an object.

Comment: @Barmar I've saw that, I've edited my answer to address it.

Comment: Might need a unique filter also based on expected results shown. OP needs to clarify

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, they seem to be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: @SMH Do you want the resulting array to be sorted in any way ?

Comment: it doesn't matter but it gives an error: ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Comment: @SMH my snipped seems to work, you probably have an error, something like `if(a = b && c = d)` (using `=` instead of `==`)

Comment: its not happy with =>

Comment: @SMH Oh, that is just an arrow function, you can replace it with a normal function (eg: `function(acc, key){.....}`)

Comment: could you please edit it as I dont know what shall I do ?

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add my 2 cents since I was following this question and working on an answer before I left work. I'm home now so I want to post what I came up with.

```js
const obj = {
  x1: { 
    y1: {
      z1: {
          h1: 'abc',
          h2: 'def'
          },
      z2: {
          h1: 123,
          h2: 456
         }
        }
  }
}

const valAll = getPropValuesAll(obj)
console.log(valAll)

function getPropValuesAll(obj, result = []){
  for(let k in obj){
    if(typeof obj[k] !== 'object'){
     result.push(obj[k])
        continue
    }
    getPropValuesAll(obj[k], result)
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy and safe answer.

```js
var myArray = [["abc1"],[["abc2",,"abc3"]],"abc4",{"r5": "abc5", "r6": "abc6"}];
var myNewArray = [];
function flatten(arr){
  if(Array.isArray(arr)){
    for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(arr[i] !== undefined){
        flatten(arr[i])
      }
    }
  } else if (typeof arr === 'object') {
    for(var key in arr){
      if(arr.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        flatten(arr[key])
      }
    }
  } else {
    myNewArray.push(arr)
  }
}
flatten(myArray)

console.log(myNewArray)
```